# How to scrape every tick data from IQO binary traderoom using python or mql5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, mql5, metatrader5

Here have a look at the image:

[image: Traderoom]

As you can see that in the image I have marked the **TickData** and the respective **Time**.
I am willing to scrape it and use it in the MT5 software or anywhere in real time. I am trying to get the live values from the binary IQOption and use it for analysis. But I am lacking ideas how I can do it.

Kindly, suggest me the way so that I can do it easily. I need guidance. Please help me.

Comment: Use requests to fetch the data and - depending on which data you can grab - beautifulsoup to parse it.

Comment: @jlaur Do you really think that is possible with beautifulsoup or bs4 library? I can guarantee you that values on the <canvas> is not possible. If it is at all possible then please share the result for understanding. You login to IQoption and then try this link and let me know: https://iqoption.com/traderoom